# How can I change the angle in this equation to show the model?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, drag

I just can't understand how I can input different angles of launch into this equation to model the said angle. The example given is at 45 degrees but how can I change that to 30 degrees, for example?

[image: Wikipedia article]om/2txSu.png

Comment: I guess that $v_{oy}=v_o\cdot \sin (\theta)$, but you should provide the entire problem, ot at least the instructions. We don't have to know what everything there means. What does every letter mean? Please, publish the problem statement

Comment: Go back to an equation in which $\theta$ is a variable. Earlier than eqn (3).

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand where the equations come from and the meaning on the parameters in the equations.

There seems to be some information missing in your post, the equations for x direction.  But assuming that there are somewhere in the text and that standard conventions are being used then,

The initial velocity in the y direction is v_0 sin(theta)

The initial velocity in the x direction is v_0 cos(theta)

The launch angle goes with the initial velocity components.